# Oracle SSL error in sqlnet.ora giving an error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I have configured the oracle wallet at server side, checked listenmer is listening on port 2484 if sqlnet.ora is not configured, but once sqlnet.ora is configured with wallet location, listener is not starting and getting the error:

> TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
>
> TNS-00583: Valid node checking: unable to parse configuration parameters

tnsping on SSL is not working.

so if sqlnet.ora we are not putting listener.ora is working fine and up and running.

we are putting this content in sqlnet.ora with wallet location for SSL

```
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=D:\oracle\Ora12c\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\wallet)))NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES,ONAMES,HOSTNAME)SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(TCPS,NTS,NONE)SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT=REQUIREDSQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256)SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT=(SHA1)#sqlnet.fallback_authentication = TRUESSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
names.default_zone=MPM
```

below s the configuration file sqlnet.ora

```
WALLET_LOCATION=
(SOURCE=
 (METHOD=FILE)
 (METHOD_DATA=
 (DIRECTORY=D:\oracle\Ora12c\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\wallet)
 )
 )
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES,ONAMES,HOSTNAME)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(TCPS,NTS,NONE)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT=(SHA1)
#sqlnet.fallback_authentication = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
NAMES.DAFAULT_DOMAIN=NPT
```

Comment: sounds like a probable syntax error in your sqlnet.ora. can you post it in your question - with IP addresses or other sensitive data obfuscated?

Comment: if trying only with wallet_location and path giving this error, with old sqlnet.ora it's working fine listener, but for SSL only issue.

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Are there any other parameters in your file? several of the parameters don't make sense if you're only doing SSL encryption. can you include accurate line breaks in your sample?

Comment: No, we have only these parameters only in sqlnet.ora, yes we are trying to setup SSL,same wallet location present in listener.ora  and when we remove sqlnet.ora, listener.ora able to start, but when putting sqlnet.ora with same wallet location listener is not starting.

Comment: Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Any suggestion on this error

Comment: Why is the first sqlnet.ora not on multiple lines?  Since you have Windows (which I don't use), maybe put the wallet path in quotes and/or use forward slashes.

Comment: last question: are you performing SSL encryption only, or encryption *and* authentication?

Comment: am setting up the wallet, and server side wallet configuration entering into client side.

Comment: any suggestions